# Execute directive code before controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I am trying to create a display loading box implementation but I seem to have some problems.Here is what I have so far:

I have created an httpInterceptor:

```
   mainModule.factory('httpLoadingInterceptorSvc', ['$q', '$injector', 'EVENTS', function ($q, $injector, EVENTS) {
        var httpInterceptorSvc = {};

        httpInterceptorSvc.request = function (request) {
            var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.LOADING_SHOW);
            return $q.when(request);
        };

        httpInterceptorSvc.requestError = function (rejection) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        };

        httpInterceptorSvc.response = function (response) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return $q.when(response);
        };

        httpInterceptorSvc.responseError = function (rejection) {
            hideLoadingBox();
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        };

        function hideLoadingBox() {
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');

            if ($http.pendingRequests.length < 1) {
                var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
                rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.LOADING_HIDE);
            }
        }

        return httpInterceptorSvc;
    }]);
```

I have then added the directive to the interceptors of the httpProvideR:

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpLoadingInterceptorSvc');
```

I then created a directive:

```
 mainModule.directive('loadingDir', ['EVENTS', function (EVENTS) {
    var loadingDir = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'App/scripts/main/directives/loading/LoadingDir.html'
    };

    loadingDir.link = function (scope, element) {
        element.hide();

        scope.$on(EVENTS.LOADING_SHOW, function () {
            element.show();
        });

        scope.$on(EVENTS.LOADING_HIDE, function () {
            element.hide();
        });
    };

    return loadingDir;
}]);
```

And then added a simple ajaxCall that alerts a message on the controller:

```
dataSvc.getCurrentDate().then(function(currentDate) {
        alert(currentDate);
    });
```

I put th edirective on the html page:

```
<loading-dir></loading-dir>
```

Now my problem is that the directive code gets executed after the controller code this makes the dierective relatively useles until the page is loaded.Is there any way to make the directive code execute before the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend a div to your page:

```
<body>

    <div controller="beforeController">

        <loading-dir></loading-dir>

    </div>

[Rest of the page]

</body>
```

And beforeController should be loaded instantly.

Comment: The problem is I need to add that directive in specific places of the page I do not want to add it globally in one place

Comment: I don't see how or why a directive could be positioned inside the page but must be loaded before the page is loaded. It doesn't make sense to me, sorry.

Comment: its probably a noobish question...I just startead learning angular 2 weeks ago I barely understand how it works:P